# Can someone tell me more about this dagger with a bronze hilt?

Tags: weapons, identification

I found this dagger whilst cleaning up. It used to belong to my father I believe; he used to collect old things. It appears to have a bronze hilt (?).

I don't see any lettering or marks on it.

I live in Belgium - this might be useful information. I am not sure if this is a real dagger (an original) or a replica of some kind. Any information would be welcome. 
[image]

[image]

Edit: More Pictures.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Did you find any lettering or marks anywhere?

Comment: @Spencer  No, I don't see any lettering or marks on it.

Comment: Normally, you should edit important information like this into your question. Since you're new, I did this for you. But feel free to revert the edit if you want to.

Comment: A bayonet maybe?

Comment: @Spencer Sorry about that :S I am not really familiar with weapons and such. Just found some that were owned by my father.

Comment: Can anyone perhaps estimate how old it could be ? I have looked on Google but have not found any that looks like this one.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is a Bohermeen style dagger. Given the hilt picture and the blade length, it look similar to a dagger discovered in a Irish bog near Dublin. This dagger now resides in the [National Museum of Ireland](http://www.navanhistory.ie/index.php?page=bronze-dagger). Unfortunately, there is no picture.

> Bronze dagger with dark patination all over. The hafting plate is roughly trapezoidal. The remains of 2 rivet holes occur on this plate. Below the hafting plate the sides are markedly concave. This evens out and the blade, oval in section, for most of its length tapers gently towards the point which is now missing. [*Navanhistory*](http://www.navanhistory.ie/index.php?page=bronze-dagger)

Comment: There is no photo offered on that site. Have you seen the Irish dagger or are you basing your answer on the text description?  Any thought to the age of the Irish dagger? I see none cited.